# Wrap a region with up / below code

Tags: text-editing

From the following code

```lisp
(defun foo () 
  (defun bar1 () 
    (do-something)))
              
(defun bar2 () 
  (do-something))
```

I want to make the following

```lisp
(defun foo () 
  (defun bar1 () 
    (do-something)))

(defun foo () 
  (defun bar2 () 
    (do-something)))
```

Note that, I have to make a copy of `foo` then replace `bar1` with `bar2` in the copied code

I wonder if I can shorten it by copying `foo`'s outer region and wrap `bar2` with the outer region

Surely, this can be done if the wrapped code is something simple like a parenthesis
(For instance, smartparens can help with that)

Comment: Why would you want to have two definitions for the same `foo`? I suspect that this is an [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/232422). Tell us what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to define foo twice, but (especially in lisp) I try to copy some skeleton of codes from somewhere, but (especially with smartparens mode) it's hard to copy the skeleton around my new code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by writing a wrapper macro for it,

```lisp
(defmacro my-foo-wrapper (body)
  `(defun foo ()
     ,body))
```

After evaluating the above code, you can use the following

```
(my-foo-wrapper
 (defun bar2 ()
   (print "test")))
```

Insert this example code in some buffer, place your cursor just after it, and do `M-x pp-macroexpand-last-sexp` to find the result you asked for.

Alternatively, you could create a [skeleton](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Using-Skeletons.html) or a [(ya)snippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) for it (or use any other alternative snippets package).